# Nested for loop with 2 variables. Ouput to be appended in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

check_df has two column one with code and other is blank
in_df has 2 column one is merged column and other is V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14.

I want to check each code of "V_ORG_UNIT_CODE" from check_df inside "merged column from in_df.
If it matches(it may contain that value may not be exact match) i want corresponding "OutputDisplay" in check_df empty column "V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"

check_df

| V_ORG_UNIT_CODE | V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14 |
| --- | --- |
| abc |  |
| def |  |
| gth |  |

in_df

| OutputDisplay | MergedColumn |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | das**abc**raf |
| 456 | asfgfdg |
| 567 | as*0def*!gfhg |

Expected Output

check_df

| V_ORG_UNIT_CODE | V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14 |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| def | 567 |
| gth | NA |

```
for x in check_df["V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"]:
    for y,z in zip(in_df["MergedColumn"],in_df["OutputDisplay"]):
        if (y.__contains__(x)):
            print(z)
            check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14']=check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14'].append(z)
```

My print(z) is correct output but I am getting error when i am appending it in a dataframe column

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e4f45d7306ae> in <module>
      3 for x in check_df["V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"]:
      4     for y,z in zip(in_df["MergedColumn"],in_df["OutputDisplay"]):
----> 5         if (y.__contains__(x)):
      6 #            print(z)
      7 #            check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14']=check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14'].append(z)

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've instantiated your dataframe correctly (check below), the following seems to deliver the outcome you're after:

```
import pandas as pd

check_df = pd.DataFrame()
in_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

First we create `check_df`:

```
check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_CODE'] = ['abc', 'def', 'gth']
check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14'] = [None, None, None]
```

`check_df` looks like this:

```
  V_ORG_UNIT_CODE V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14
0             abc                    None
1             def                    None
2             gth                    None
```

Then we create `in_df`:

```
in_df['OutputDisplay'] = [123, 456, 567]
in_df['MergedColumn'] = ['dasabcraf', 'asfgfdg', 'as0def!gfhg']
```

`in_df` looks like this:

```
   OutputDisplay MergedColumn
0            123    dasabcraf
1            456      asfgfdg
2            567  as0def!gfhg
```

I've then kept your code essentially unchanged, except I use `enumerate` to get both every item in the first column of `check_df` and also its index as `i`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(check_df["V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"]): 
    for y, z in zip(in_df["MergedColumn"], in_df["OutputDisplay"]):
        if x in y:
            check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14'][i]=z
        
print (check_df)
```

Which produces this result:

```
  V_ORG_UNIT_CODE V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14
0             abc                     123
1             def                     567
2             gth                    None
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yes i want that output but It gives me below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-be443b287e38> in <module>
      4 for i,x in enumerate(check_df["V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"]):
      5     for y,z in zip(in_df["MergedColumn"],in_df["V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14"]):
----> 6         if x in y:
      7             check_df['V_ORG_UNIT_NAME_LEVEL14'][i]=z
      8 #            print(z)

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: i just changed type to Str and it worked. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

check ,5 line "y value" type, that must be string type

Answer (score 0):

try the DataFrame class built-in function .insert

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html